# How to layout buttons to be stacked on mobile device?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a simple page with the following code:

```css
body {
  font: 600 14px/24px "Open Sans", "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  background: #eaeaed;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.container,
section,
aside {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

section,
aside {
  background: #2db34a;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 1.858736059%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

@media all and (min-width: 420px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 538px;
  }
  section {
    float: left;
    width: 63.197026%;
  }
  aside {
    float: right;
    width: 29.3680297%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CSS Responsive</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <section>Section</section>
    <aside>Aside</aside>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The buttons are positioned next to each other on wider screen, but when I shrink the browser's width it doesn't make them stacked as in this example:

https://codepen.io/shayhowe/pen/KcApz

I use the same code.

It doesn't work in Chrome, but it works in Firefox.

It looks as following in Chrome:

[image]

And I'm not able to shrink it more.

How to make it work in Chrome?

Comment: Seems to be working fine on Chrome ?

Comment: Please check it again it is working on chrome, firefox and safari. thans

Comment: I've checked it again and it doesn't work. Please, take a look at the screen shot I've added above.

Comment: @tesicg Open inspector tool (F12 or Ctrl + Shift + i) on the left top side, there is a mobile icon. Click to open mobile preview, you can choose the device you want from the list at top.

Comment: 449px wide is not narrow enough for the buttons to be stacked according to your css. You need to resize it to smaller than 420px wide.

Comment: @Akshay: I've already did it and it works fine there, but not in browser.

Comment: @tesicg Maybe you didn't resize the browser below 420px ?

Comment: @josephting: I can't shrink it anymore. The right edge of browser's window doesn't move to the left anymore.

Comment: @tesicg That's why the Mobile Preview is more helpful, its better than resizing the browser

Comment: @tesicg Use [device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Chrome, it seems to be working fine. But I would explore the use of `display: grid` to help you with stacking and moving the different elements around inside another element.

It's not fully 100% supported throughout all browsers (https://caniuse.com/#search=grid), but it works in Chrome, it is extremely helpful to remove all of the use of `::after` and `::before`.

Explore more here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

**Edit:**
You can't shrink Chrome more because that is the limit that the Chrome app allows to be shrunk to. If you want to see a smaller veiwport, enable Developer Tools (press 12), and try shrinking your browser then.

Also, your css styling may be cached in your browser. Refresh the page buy pressing `SHIFT`+`F5`.

Comment: I've already did it with DevTools and it works fine. If it's shrink limitation in Chrome, I understand it now. Thanks.